# Language Design issues with including libraries

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, language-design, code-translation

I'm writing a compiler that will compile a language I made (called [SLang](https://github.com/DragonToothSoftware/SLang) (currently those files are a few pushes behind, not that its important)) into C++ (eventually ELF, Mach-O, and PE but that will come later).  This is my first compiler, and was wondering the best way to include libraries?  In c/c++, libraries are just imported by being copied and pasted (at its worst. I'm sure some more complicated things go on there). Is this the best way to do it for a compiler? Is there a more efficient way for someone that wouldn't be able to match the gcc/visual c++/clang preprocessor? Thank you in advance for any help you can give. Just to be clear, I am not asking for specific code, just ideas on how to do it.

*Side Note* If anyone knows of any compiler specific forums or irc channels, I would love to know what they were.  I have looked and looked and have yet to find one, other than specific ones for a product, such as #gcc or #clang.

edit: I misspoke above. I am aware that just the header file is pasted into the file including it, and then the linker links source files with more source files and/or libraries.  I am still however looking for the most efficient way of including libraries without writing a linker for SLang

Comment: No, in C and C++ libraries are not "copy-pasted", only the header files. The actual code lies in the actual library which you have to link with.

Comment: im sorry thats what i meant. the header file is pasted into the file including it, then the linker will link the source files or libraries together. I just misspoke. I will edit it though to reflect what i meant

Comment: In the past newsgroup comp.lang.misc had a lot of small language implementers. comp.compilers exists too, but is moderated, and you'd find less experiences there. (a lot of odd ball parsing theory). As for how programs come together, study how the module system (and building is organized) it works in e.g. Java/C# or for a different view, Pascal/Delphi.  The latter is also interesting, because there is no hard need for a complete list of modules and dependencies in the project (-administration). For pascal questions use freenode #fpc

Comment: alright... thank you. ill take a look at those! youve been great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide a small "Hello World" example of your programming language, and, you link, did not show any example, directly.

Trying to do something similar, in the past.

You may want to take a look to D, since it's a similar known case:

http://dlang.org/index.html

Most programming languages does not have header files, but, may generate header files, if compiled to C or C++.

How does your compiler / programming language handles separate files ?
How does your compiler / programming language locates separate files ?

I suggest your programming language support namespaces or modules. "Plain C", and "PHP", did not have namespaces originally.

Something like:

---

File: "CollectionExample.sprg"

---

```
namespace CollectionExample;

import Collections = "c:\\slang\\Collections.slib";

...

void main()
{
  // do something with definitions in "Collections"
}    
...
```

---

It may generate C++ files like:

---

File: "CollectionExample.hpp"

---

### ...

And:

---

File: "CollectionExample.cpp"

---

```
#include "c:\\slang\\Collections.hpp"
#include "c:\\slang\\CollectionExample.hpp"
...
```

---

I also suggest, that, in your programming language, use a different file extension or file suffix from libraries, than the main program.

Cheers.